# How to use gdal_rasterize to create a LZW compressed Tiff

Tags: gis, gdal, lzw

I want to use `gdal_rasterize` to generate a TIFF from a `.shp` shapefile. Usually the result is big, so I want to compress it using the [LZW compress option](http://gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html#overviews).

I tried to do so with the command

```
gdal_rasterize.exe -burn 255 -burn 255 -burn 0 -burn 255 -ot Byte -tr 0.0332147 0.0332147 shp.shp shp0.tif --config COMPRESS LZW
```

but it seems the `--config COMPRESS LZW` option doesn't have any effect. (The result is exactly the same size as without the option.)

Maybe I have some misunderstanding of how to use this option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add an `=` symbol between the option and the value. Without your data i cant test your specific example, but for me this fails:

```
gdal_translate --config COMPRESS LZW infile.tif outfile.tif
```

and this works fine:

```
gdal_translate --config COMPRESS=LZW infile.tif outfile.tif
```

You can also write the `--config` as `-co`, and wrapping it with quotes also works, which is how i usually do it.

```
gdal_translate -co "COMPRESS=LZW" infile.tif outfile.tif
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works. Besides, you may have a misunderstanding of --config. My GDAL version is 1.10. `gdal_translate -co "COMPRESS=LZW" infile.tif outfile.tif` works for me. But `gdal_translate --config COMPRESS=LZW infile.tif outfile.tif` ends up with a failure. So --config is not equal to -co. ( ^_^ ) I'm new here, with not enough repution to give an up. ( ^_^ )

Comment: There not identical indeed, `--config` is a GDAL configuration option and `-co` is a (driver) creation option. Im pretty sure both ways work for me, ive tested it before answering, but i'll have another look later. Glad you've got it working.